# Reusing Message in the same package in multiple files

Tags: go, serialization, encoding, protocol-buffers, protobuf-go

Is there a way to reuse protobuf structs across multiple proto files?

in the `client.proto`  file I have the following

```
message SingleOperation {
  string command = 1;
}

message ClientBatch {
  string unique_id = 1;
  repeated SingleOperation requests = 2;
  int64 sender = 3;
}
```

Then in `network.proto`  file, I have the following

```
message MemPool {
  int32 sender = 1;
  string unique_id = 2;
  SingleOperation op = 3;
}
```

In the `network.proto` file, I need to reuse the `SingleOperation` message.

However, I do not see an option to do this.

Does protobuff support some sort of packaging to support struct reuse?

Comment: I think adding import "client.proto"; in network.proto file should work fine.

Comment: Yes, as Zaid says, "import" is the way to go. Structure your .proto files much like you would .h files in C, or class libraries; you might (for example) have a "sharedmessages.proto" containing all the message definitions you use in multiple places. Import that into other files.